# Freeing a buffer right after passing it to curl_slist_append

Tags: c, curl, malloc, buffer

The curl_slist_append function is defined like this:

```
struct curl_slist *curl_slist_append(struct curl_slist * list, const char * string );
```

Can the code below cause a Segmentation Fault because I'm freeing the buffer before the actual curl call is made?

```
    char *buf = malloc(strlen(callname)+strlen("X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: ")+1);
    sprintf(buf, "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: %s", callname);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, buf);
    free(buf);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [doco](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_slist_append.html) states that `curl_slist_append()` *copies* the string, so freeing the original should have no impact.

> `curl_slist_append()` appends a specified string to a linked list of strings. The existing list should be passed as the first argument while the new list is returned from this function. The specified string has been appended when this function returns. **`curl_slist_append()` copies the string.**

One thing that *could* cause a fault would be if the `malloc()` call fails, something you're not actually checking before attempting the `sprintf()`.

In addition, the actual append itself may fail in which case `headers` will be set to NULL. Truly paranoid coders (and they're more often than not the best kind) would check for both of those possibilities.